# Inside of a scrolling div, offset and position do not properly give dimensions in term of the top of the doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scrolling div, which has enough controls to scroll. Which all flow in a block display.  when scrolling down, when i was to take a snapshot of all the elements, i was wanting to get the list of all the positions and print them out.   The issue at hand is that when scrolling, things that are out of view (towards the top) have a neg. position.

I was looking at offset and Position, but they both arent giving me the numbers i was wanting.

How would i get the X:Y positions of all the children, from the top of the div?  IE:  [0,0], [0,20], [0,40] etc etc.

Is there another variable i am not making use of?  some sort of scrollY or something which should be appended to adjust everything?

**Edit:** When dealing with scrollable divs, making use of:   `$.scrollTop` gives the offset, which would need to be applied to all the children. when getting the position of all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, it sounds like you want scrollTop, i.e.

```
document.getElementById('div1').scrollTop;
```

...which you can get and set.   If I've misudnderstood, perhaps you could create a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes thats exactly it! :)   scrollTop in javascript, and scrollTop() in jQuery.

Thank you very much!